# Media recorder failure on outgoing phone call

Tags: java, android, mediarecorder

I am trying to record an outgoing phone call in my class which extends BroadcastReceiver and I am seeing two failure:

1. This one appears right after the start recording function -

> E/MediaRecorder: start failed: -38

2. This error appears after I am calling the prepare function -

> E/Media_APM :: isCalledPackage return false

I must mention that when I run it on the simulator I do not see those errors (but you can't test a phone call recording on a simulator), I only see those error when I run the app on Samsung Galaxy 8 (with Android Pie installed) and Samsung Note 20 (with Android Pie installed).
When I run it on Xiaomi Mi A9 (With Android Q installed) it does not fail but also doesn't record anything - I see the audio file, it's in the right length but it's empty).

This is my code:

```
public class CallBr extends BroadcastReceiver {
    Bundle bundle;
    String state;

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (Objects.equals(intent.getAction(), ACTION_IN)) {
            if ((bundle = intent.getExtras()) != null) {
                state = bundle.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
                if (state != null && state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)) {
                    if (shouldStartRecording) {
                        recorder = new MediaRecorder();
                        recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_COMMUNICATION);
                        recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
                        recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
                        File callAudioFile = null;
                        try {
                            File downloadsDir = context.getApplicationContext().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
                            callAudioFile = File.createTempFile("deTuCelRecord", ".amr", downloadsDir);
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        assert callAudioFile != null;
                        audioFilePath = callAudioFile.getAbsolutePath();

                        recorder.setOutputFile(audioFilePath);
                        try {
                            recorder.setOnErrorListener(new MediaRecorder.OnErrorListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onError(MediaRecorder mr, int what, int extra) {
                                    Log.e("MediaRecorder", "MediaRecorder error " + what + " " + extra);
                                }
                            });
                            recorder.prepare();
                        } catch (Error e) {
                            Log.e("RecPrep", "So there was an error ...");
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Log.d("RecPrep", "Did you get what that error was?");
                        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Log.e("RecPrep", "startRecording: ", e);
                        }
                        recorder.start();
                        recordStarted = true;
                        shouldStartRecording = false;
                    }
                    shouldStartRecording = true;
                }
                if (state != null && state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {
                    if (recordStarted) {
                        recorder.stop();
                        recorder.release();
                        convertToAmr();
                        compareAudioFiles(context);
                        recordStarted = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```